# Odd behavior when removing action buttons from a table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a page that builds a table using DataTables, and each row has an Action Button that adds some data (an ID, just an int) from that row to a list. To keep users from clicking each action button multiple times, I made it so a row's button is removed the first time you click it. This worked great until I realized the buttons come back if you switch to the next page of the table and then switch back to the first page.

To fix this, I wrote some JS to compare each row to my list of data, and if that row's data is already in the list, it removes that row's action button. This happens each time the table is reloaded (for example, when you switch to a different page of the table and back again) using DataTable's `draw.dt` function.

The problem is, when I switch pages and the JavaScript goes to work removing buttons, for some reason it *skips every other row*. For example, if I click (thus removing) the first three rows' action buttons, switch pages and switch back, my JS removes the action buttons on row 1, 3, and 5 instead of rows 1, 2, and 3. It's so consistent that it has to be some kind of simple looping error due to my sloppy JS skills, but I can't find it.

**Here is the code:**

```
$(document).on('draw.dt', function () {
    var $allSerialNumbers = $('.box-electrode'); // This is a list of all the rows' action buttons / ID's

    $('#electrodes li').each(function (i, li) { // This is the list of ID's I'm comparing to
        var $id = $(li).data('id');
        for(var index = 0; index < $allSerialNumbers.length; index++){
            if($id == $allSerialNumbers.eq(index).attr('data-id')){ // For each item in my ID list, run through all the rows and see if any Action Button ID's match any on the list
                $('.box-electrode').eq(index).remove(); // If they do match, remove that Action Button 
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: insert `console.log($id+' == '+$allSerialNumbers.eq(index).attr('data-id');` after the `for()` loop and see what the logs says. It probably that right there which is causing the issue. Post a JFiddle with the info and I can take a deeper look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on JQuery, but could `remove()` in your last line be re-sizing the list so that the element which used to be at index 1 is now at index 0, causing you to skip it when you increment the index?

Comment: Yes, this is very possible. I read that iterating through the loop backwards could fix this, but when I tried that it didn't work. Are there any other simple ways to get around this?

Comment: What went wrong when you tried to iterate backwards? Same problem?

Comment: Yeah, same problem.. nothing seemed to be different.

Comment: One way to test whether this is the issue would be to click some rows but skip others. So for example, instead of 1, 2, 3, -> 1, 3, 5, you could try 1, 2, 4 and see if it comes out 1, 3, 6.

Comment: Hmm.. I just did 1, 2, and 4 and it removed only 1 and 3.

Comment: What's really weird is that if I click the rows from bottom to top, everything works correctly. For example, clicking rows 3, 2, 1 works correctly but clicking 1, 2, 3 does not.