# Need help fixing a loop that skips every other item (JavaScript, JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214864/odd-behavior-when-removing-action-buttons-from-a-table-in-javascript/42215085?noredirect=1#comment71592121_42215085) the other day, which I'd rather not rehash the details of here again.

Essentially I wrote a loop that goes through each row in a table and removes buttons. The problem was that it was skipping rows for some reason.

I eventually concluded that it was because every time a button was removed, the loop had one less button/row to loop through, and that threw off the loop's index.

To fix this, I created a `fixer` number that increments by 1 every time a button is removed, to counteract the index getting throw off and skipping. Then when it loops, it subtracts the `fixer` amount from the index so it will always be on track.

```
$(document).on('draw.dt', function () {
    var $allSerialNumbers = $('.box-electrode');
    var fixer = 0;
    $('#electrodes li').each(function (i, li) {
        var $id = $(li).data('id');
        for (var index = 0; index < $allSerialNumbers.length; index++) {
            if ($id == $allSerialNumbers.eq(index).attr('data-id')) {
                $('.box-electrode').eq(index - fixer).remove();
                fixer++;
                break;
            }
        }
    })
});
```

This works really well when you remove buttons in ascending order (ex: I remove buttons 1, 2, and 3) but it now skips rows if I remove them backwards (I remove buttons 3, 2, and then 1).

This is the exact opposite problem I had before, where I could remove buttons in a descending order and things would be fine, but not ascending. Now it's the reverse with my `fixer`.

Is there some other way to solve this problem?

**Note:** Sorry if some of this doesn't make sense. It's explained more thoroughly in the original question from the other day, linked at the top. I wanted to keep this post clean since it's asking about a specific solution, and the previous post was simply trying to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question? What is requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way would be to use the attribute as a selector in a [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var $allSerialNumbers = $('.box-electrode');

$('#electrodes li').each(function (i, li) {
     var id = $(li).data('id');
     $allSerialNumbers.filter('[data-id="' + id + '"]').remove(); 
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and is much simpler than what I was trying. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not save all of the elements in the loop and when the loop ends then delete them all:

```
   var toDelete = []; 
    $('#electrodes li').each(function (i, li) {
            var $id = $(li).data('id');
            for (var index = 0; index < $allSerialNumbers.length; index++) {
                if ($id == $allSerialNumbers.eq(index).attr('data-id')) {
                  toDelete.push($('.box-electrode').eq(index))
                    break;
                }
            }
        })
    toDelete.forEach(function(element){
      element.remove();
    })
```